Show tooltip values in Vega_Lite timeseries stepplot for dates where there is no data point
Based on the Multi Series Line Chart with Tooltip example, we started to develop a stepplot. Now our dataset is rather sparse, meaning there is many days w/o data and ussually there is only data for one category at a given date.
We would like that the tooltip shows values for all categories as indicated below in red as opoosed to only the value that is available at the given date.

Here's the vega online editor version
EDIT
here's the current version where we try various transforms
The data to look at is in data 2. Something like forward fill would be straight forward, but we can't get it to work properly.


Impute is the way to go. How come you deleted you answer - did something not work?

It seemed to work with impute, but only for the data with alternating values for A and B. With unevenly spaced data it did not work. I added the link to the vega editor with our current playing field (trying out different transforms) to the main question. Link was too long for comments.

We didn't find a proper solution to this, so we moved the data transformation into the SQL layer so that we have values for both A and B at each given date. Then the code from the vega lite example works like a charm.

Definitely better to do this type of data work upstream
